# AWS Elastic Load Balancer on a Single Instance containing two instance of application running on different ports

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have two application on a single EC2 instance running on ports 8090 and 8091. I want to use a single ELB for these two instances and both the applications are same.

But for same ELB port I cant map different listeners 
ie 8080 -> 8090
   8080 -> 8091
I want that whenever i hit the ELB either one of the two application in 8090 or 8091 should be invoked.

Comment: Having only one instance behind the ELB defeats the purpose of a load balancer. If that instance goes down then your site is down. 

You say the applications are the same, so why not just startup a second instance and load balance between the two?

Answer (score 0):

ELB doesn't support mapping to a specific host. ELB only maps its port to a port for the backend instances. You could use TWO ELBs with DNS round robin? Another option would be to setup HAProxy as a roll your own solution for load balancing.